# How to point on first content image when you share article on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, joomla

I have page http://www.aboutphuket.ru/Glavnaya/Putevoditel-po-stranam-yugo-vostochnoiy-%D0%90zii/Putevoditel-po-Taiylandu/Taiyskiiy-yazik/S-chego-nachat-izuchenie-taiyskogo-yazika.html ; when I try to share it on Facebook, I can't choose images from article, Facebook takes banners or any other pictures.

I read here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices about this META tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://graphics.myfavnews.com/images/logo-100x100.jpg" />
```

But how can I insert first image from article in this tag in my template?

Answer (score 1):

These are usually created dynamically set by the page loading it if they support facebook opengraph tags.

I would suggest trying a plugin like the Phoca Opentags for Joomla! see:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/phoca-open-graph